# how to create a view pager which first show only PagerTitleStrip and after end AsyncTask show viewpager content

Tags: android, android-viewpager

when I create view pager by PagerTitleStrip, should define adapter for viewpager so I can use tabs.setViewPager, but content viewpager receive by AsyncTask, so I can't use tabs.setViewPager and show PagerTitleStrip until receive viewpager content and set adapter for view pager. but I want show PagerTitleStrip before recieve content.

**how to create a view pager which first show only PagerTitleStrip and after end AsyncTask show viewpager content.**

Comment: First you find out if it is possible to only show PagerTitles without PagerContents

Answer (score 0):

initialay make content invisible then in `onPostExecute()` make it visible

use this code

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    super.onPreExecute();


}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //do your stuff here
    return myString;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);
    //do something with result here
    //then display content here
}

}
```